# Reading object from a file and saving it into ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

I have a problem with reading specific object from a file and saving it into ArrayList.

First I write a single customer using `writeCustomer()`. Then I write all records from `List customerList` and save them to the file. This works great.

Then I want to read the saved file so I read one line using `readCustomer()`. This method returns one `Customer` and then I want to return a list with all `Clients` using `readData()` and read it,  I have nullPointerException in line list.add(readCustomer(bufferedReader));

My `Class Customer` has one constructor and is has an override method `toString()`.

```
public class SaveCustomers {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<Customers> customersList = new ArrayList<>();
    customersList.add(new Customers("ABC", 10));
    customersList.add(new Customers("SGS", 20));
    customersList.add(new Customers("FSD", 30));

    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("customer.txt", "UTF-8"))
    {         writeData(customersList, out);      }


    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("customer.txt"));
    List<Customers> newList =  readData(bufferedReader);


    for(Customers c: newList){
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}

private static void writeCustomer(PrintWriter out, Customers customers){
    out.println(customers.getName()+"|"+customers.getTarrif());
}

private static void writeData(List<Customers> customersList, PrintWriter out){
    for(Customers c:customersList){
        writeCustomer(out, c);
    }
}

public static Customers readCustomer(BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws IOException {
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    String [] tokens = line.split("\\|");
    String name = tokens[0];
    int time = Integer.valueOf(tokens[1]);
    return new Customers(name, time);
}

public static List<Customers> readData(BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws IOException {

    List<Customers> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) {
            list.add(readCustomer(bufferedReader));
        }
    return list;
}}
```

Comment: "*I have a problem.... it doesn't work*"--what exactly happens? Exception? Wrong ouput? Infinite loop?

Comment: Thank you Sasha for decreasing my reputation. I hope that thanks you did it you have better mood....

Comment: I didn't downvote if you're interested. Comment sometimes is just a comment. Most people who downvote don't comment at all.

Comment: Sasha, sorry. You're great guy and you were very helpfull.

Comment: @bartek1982 Improved English but unfortunately the question is still of low quality. Could you please edit your post and tell what "it doesn't work" means?

Comment: Hello Frank, I just edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to the solution ;)

In method :

```
readData(BufferedReader bufferedReader)
```

Just change this line

```
for(Customers l : list) {
```

to this one :

```
while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
```

Comment: Thank you Ben. It works quiet good. My output looks like:BC 10
GS 20
SD 30. But it's Something for begin :)

Comment: It's strange,  bufferedReader.readLine(); returns BC|10 although there is ABC|10 in the customer.txt file...

Comment: Ok use while (bufferedReader.ready()) { instead of while (bufferedReader.read() != -1) { 
(solution edited)

Comment: Ben my fault. I put read() instead of ready()... It works. Thank you!!! When I'm using bufferedReader.readLine() != null, I have nullPointerException in line list.add(readCustomer(bufferedReader));. Do you have idea why can't use it? Thanks much for your help!!!

Comment: NullPointerException in line list.add(readCustomer(bufferedReader)) means list is null.